# Input from previous scanf appends to another scanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

The program asks the user for input of names, IDs, etc, of 2 students, writes the data to a file and reads the data back from the file.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int fd, i = 0;
    char name[20], id[10], dob[10], gender[7], status[10];
    fd = open("file.dat", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRWXU); //open file.dat for writing; if it does not exist, create it
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        //get input from user
        printf("\nFor student %d\n", (i + 1));
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name); //%[^\n]%*c - read everything up to (excluding) new line character
        printf("Enter ID: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", id);
        printf("Enter date of birth: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", dob);
        printf("Enter gender: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", gender);
        printf("Enter marital status: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", status);
        //write current student to file
        write(fd, name, 20);
        write(fd, id, 10);
        write(fd, dob, 10);
        write(fd, gender, 7);
        write(fd, status, 10);
    }
    close(fd);
    //display data from file
    char buf[20];
    fd = open("file.dat", O_RDONLY); //open file for reading
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("\nFor student %d\n", (i + 1));
        read(fd, buf, 20); //read name
        printf("Name: %s\n", buf);
        read(fd, buf, 10); //read id
        printf("ID: %s\n", buf);
        read(fd, buf, 10); //read date of birth
        printf("Date of birth: %s\n", buf);
        read(fd, buf, 7); //read gender
        printf("Gender: %s\n", buf);
        read(fd, buf, 10); //read marital status
        printf("Marital status: %s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

The input part:

**For student 1 

Enter name: Mary Jane Smith

Enter ID: 1

Enter date of birth: 09/09/1990

Enter gender: Female

Enter marital status: Single


For student 2

Enter name: John Doe Paul

Enter ID: 2

Enter date of birth: 08/08/1993

Enter gender: Male

Enter marital status: Married**

The display part:

**For student 1

Name: Mary Jane Smith

ID: 1

Date of birth: 09/09/1990Smith

Gender: Female

Marital status: Single


For student 2

Name: John Doe Paul

ID: 2

Date of birth: 08/08/1993aul

Gender: Male

Marital status: Married**

Some part of the name gets added to the date of birth. Why is this so and how do I solve this, please?

I have read that scanf is not reliable but I am required to use scanf in the program.

Comment: `read()` doesn't nul-terminate.

Comment: `09/09/1990` need 11 instead of 10. `dob[10]` --> `dob[11]`

Comment: @EOF

Can you please explain?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY

I changed dob[10] to dob[11] but I still get the same error.

Comment: The main cause is EOF has already been pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue there is not in the scanf. The issue is in your buffer handling when you re-read the file. When you read the file, you read it repeatedly in buffer "buf", that is not reset in any way. Consequently, when you read 10 characters from your file, the previously inserted 20 characters from the name are still in the buffer and hence are displayed. You need to either terminate your strings properly (with '\0') or set your buffer to all-zeroes when you use it to ensure you won't get "old content" back.

Comment: I set the buffer to all-zeroes using memset(buf, 0, 20).